# Please help me identify this font

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image: sjmarket]
Could anyone please help me with this?
I really couldn't find it anywhere even with automated font searches.

By the way, AFAIR all of these letters are capital ones, just lowered down by resizing.

Comment: Go to this site and put image of text
https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cassannet Plus](http://www.identifont.com/list?2+cassannet+3.4+4CWL+1+4D1W+44+4D1X+46+4D1Y+71) via identifont.com

[image]

[image]